# Cannot run python script in command line

Tags: python

I am currently trying to run a little script on a raspberry pi in order to survey my power consumption.

This script normally get an interruption each time my counter does an impulsion (close contact) and calculate a "instant" power consumption.

The problem is that this script work perfectly when I run it from an IDE (Thonny) but I can't run it directly in command line (python or python3, sudo or not, & at the end...). My goal is to run it as a service appealing "python3 myscript.py". I get no message, error or anything when I run it. it just seems to stop.
Here is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import mysql.connector as mariadb
import datetime
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='Elec', password='****', database='Elec')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT datetime FROM Compteur ORDER BY nb DESC LIMIT 1")
gett = cursor.fetchone()
last = gett[0]
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def impulse(channel):
    global last
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = datetime.timedelta.total_seconds(now-last)
    last = datetime.datetime.now()
    Pinst = round(3.6/delta ,3)
    heure = int(now.strftime("%H"))
    if heure > 20 or heure < 7:
        HPHC = 'HC'
    else:
        HPHC = 'HP'

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Compteur (Puiss,datetime,HPHC) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", 
    (Pinst,now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), HPHC))
    mariadb_connection.commit()

GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.FALLING, callback=impulse, bouncetime=500)
```

I'm running out of idea so please if you have anything to try... Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you try Idiot-Debugging yet? (I.e., putting `print` statements after every major step, so you can see where it stops).

Comment: Or learn Python's builtin debugger which is always available on command line.

Comment: Have you tried omitting "&" in the end of the call. & will start the script in the background and not print any output to the terminal.

Comment: Actually I found a "tricky" way to make it work. I added a while True at the end in order to maintain the script active. Does anyone know any other way to keep the script execution alive waiting for an interruption ? Thanks anyway for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my script is now running for some times. I modified it in order to control the tariff switch with a relay. This may interest someone, who knows :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import mysql.connector as mariadb
import datetime
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='', password='', 
database='')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
print ('connected')
cursor.execute("SELECT datetime FROM Compteur ORDER BY nb DESC LIMIT 1")
gett = cursor.fetchone()
last = gett[0]
print (last)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
HPHC = ''

def impulse(channel):
    global last
    global HPHC
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    #print (now)
    delta = datetime.timedelta.total_seconds(now-last)
    #print (delta)
    last = datetime.datetime.now()
    Pinst = round(7.2/delta ,3)
    #print (Pinst)
    heure = int(now.strftime("%H"))
    minute = int(now.strftime("%M"))
    #print(heure,minute)
    if heure == 20 and minute >= 56 :
        HPHC = 'HC'
    elif heure > 20:
        HPHC = 'HC'
    elif heure == 4 and minute <= 56 :
        HPHC = 'HC'
    elif heure < 4:
        HPHC = 'HC'
    else :
        HPHC = 'HP'
    #print (HPHC)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Compteur (Puiss,datetime,HPHC) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (Pinst,now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), HPHC))
    mariadb_connection.commit()
    return HPHC

GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.FALLING, callback=impulse, bouncetime=500)
print ('boucle')

while True:
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if HPHC is 'HC' :
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
    elif HPHC is 'HP' :
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
```